# Equivalence relation question help with x+y

Tags: equivalence-relations

Need help with this question:

**Explain whether the relation $(x\sim y)=\left\{(x,y)∈N\times N\bigg|x+y\text{ is even}\right\}$ is transitive where N is the set of Natural numbers.**

I've tried to work this question out but the $+$ sign is confusing me, if it was a $<$ (less than) then I would be able to solve it but I don't know what it means in equivalence relation when its $x+y$.
Someone please help.

Comment: Why "equivalence relation" ? The question ask if it is [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation).

Comment: You to check that if $xRy$ and $yRz$, then $xRz$. I.e. $x+y$ is even and $y+z$ is even, then $x+z$ is ?

Comment: then x + z is even right ?

Comment: Correct: $xRy$ is $x+y=2k$ and $yRz$ is $y+z=2m$. Thus $x+z = (x+y)+(y+z)-2y=2k+2m-2y=2(k+m-y)$.

Answer (score 2):

The relation isn't $x+y$. The relation is "$x\sim y$ iff $x+y$ is even" or equivalently, $x\sim y$ iff $x$ and $y$ have the same parity.

The rephrasing should make the transitivity of the relation immediate.

Answer (score 2):

$2\mid(x+y) \land 2\mid(y+z) \implies 2\mid((x+y)-2y+(y+z)) = x+z$ because obviously $2\mid 2y$